# Idealizations of an object as a point particle

Tags: classical-mechanics, approximations, point-particles

Why is it that an object can be idealized as a point particle or 'particle like' to solve problems? What are the limits of such a tool?

Comment: It should be noted that while in vectorial mechanics, a point is _isolated_ from the whole system, in analytical mechanics, the whole system is considered without decomposing it into into individual points. Then we can transform the body concerned by a one-to-one correspondence from the regular coordinates to the abstract realms of more general  Configuration space where the body though composed of infinitely many points is considered as a __single__ point known as _Configuration point_. All the regular coordinates can be expressed as the function of generalised coordinates.

Comment: A rigid body can be considered a point mass , when the force acting on it is purely translational , that is relative velocity between any two points on the body is zero. If there is deformation of the body or rotational component of force is present, then the point mass approximation is not valid.

Comment: What research have you done to find an answer? What thoughts do you have about the question?

Comment: I found some interesting information on Wikipedia. I did not find anything like a proof of why it works or its limitations.